# Odds of two consecutive numbers in 10,000 on 365 draws

Tags: probability

What are the odds of drawing two consecutive numbers on successive draws?  $10,000$ numbers in the pot.  $365$ draws total.

For example (draw: number drawn)

$$
\begin{matrix}
1: & 5432 \\
2: & 2290 \\
3: & 8832* \\
4: & 8833* \\
5: & 1002 \\
\!\!\! \vdots & \vdots  \\
364: & 4289 \\
365: & 9123
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: How about 1:5432 2:2290 3:8833* 4:8832*?  Does that count?

Comment: Do we assume 10000 is adjacent to 1?

Comment: Is a number replaced in the pot after it is drawn?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  To a very good approximation, after the first draw the chance of drawing a neighboring number to the previous is $\frac 2{10000}$, so the chance you don't get a neighboring one is $\frac {9998}{10000}$  You need to do this $364$ times in a row....

Comment: Are you sure? I believe the OP is drawing 365 numbers and trying to find the probability of any two of them being adjacent. (Also, that would necessarily be w/o replacement.)

Comment: @Newb:  That is how I took successive draws.